Unitary Transformation for a Self-Adjoint Elliptic Operator in one dimension
Let $a\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}_+$ be bounded, bounded from below by a strictly positive constant and Lipschitz-continuous. Consider the self-adjoint linear operator $L:=-\partial_x a(x)\partial_x$ (in divergence form) on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with domain $D(L)=H^2(\mathbb{R})$. By the spectral theorem for self-adjoint operators, $L$ is unitary equivalent to a multiplication operator, i.e., there is some $\sigma$-finite measure space ($\Omega, \mu$) and some unitary operator $U\colon L^2(\Omega)\to L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and a multiplication operator $M\colon L^2(\Omega)\to L^2(\Omega)$ such that $L=UMU^*$. Is it possible to describe such a unitary operator "more explicitly"? For example, if $a=1$ is constant, then it is well known that $U$ can be chosen to be the $\textbf{Fourier transform}$. Here, I am curious about the more general case when $a\neq 1$.
I would appreciate any hints or references connected to this question.
